# Issuing a Docker command while in another container

Tags: docker

Is there a way to issue a docker command to another container within a different one such as `docker stop`? I am not sure if this is even possible, but are there any valid workarounds for this? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can issue docker commands to different containers using their respective container id e.g. `docker stop <container_id>`. Their respective identifier can be retrieved using `docker ps -a` Where `-a` means - ALL containers.

Comment: @Samuel I need to send that docker command to a container from a script in another container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.   Mount the docker socket into a container, something like:

```
 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Then issue [API Commands](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/).   For reference, checkout [DockerUI](https://github.com/kevana/ui-for-docker).

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would I need to configure both containers in order for one to be able to communicate to the other with a docker command?

Comment: AFAIK, Just map the socket into the container that needs to do the controlling.   It can then control any docker container on that server.